# Nginx redirect from one domain to another?

Tags: nginx

I'm on the process of migrating the same app but to a different domain.

For the old domain, I've the routes as:

```
http://app.example.com/app/users/sign_in?query=hello
```

I want it to be redirected to another domain omitting the `app` part as:

```
http://app.newexample.com/users/sign_in?query=hello
```

I tried with:

```
server {
  ...
  location /app {
    rewrite ^$scheme://app.sparkon.com/app(/.*)$ $1 last;
  }
  ...
}
```

I doesn't work. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put scheme in the rewrite pattern:

```
server {
    server_name app.example.com;
    location /app/ {
        rewrite ^/app/(.*)$ http://app.newexample.com/$1;
    }
}
```

Brg.

Comment: Can u plz read the question one more time. I want the `/app` to be dropped/deleted.

Comment: How can I attach extra headers like Referrer with the above rewrite?

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue about a year ago and spent a long time looking for solutions. I found and use this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com app.example.com;
    rewrite ^/app(.*)$ http://app.newexample.com$1 permanent;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.newexample.com;
    # config for primary domain here
}
```

From [this link](http://www.base-10.net/blog/2010/11/04/nginx-how-to-forward-multiple-domains-to-a-primary-domain/). Credit to them.

Comment: Can u plz read the question one more time. I want the `/app` to be dropped/deleted.

Comment: Replace this line: `rewrite ^(.*) http://app.newexample.com$1 permanent;` with `rewrite ^/app(.*)$ http://app.newexample.com$1 permanent;` then.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this method as it doesn't need to use rewrite, one of the things that i read are good to avoid too much, cause it needs more processing by the nginx engine.

```
  location ~ /app/(.*) {
    return 301 $scheme://app.sparkon.com/$1;  
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, for the another version. But can you point me on how to add an extra header that I can use over at app.sparkon.com?